# Api parameters in the open api documentation ( Swagger ) are getting sorted automatically per user browser

Tags: python, swagger-ui, openapi-generator

I have a python application. due to the issue in the api bluprint url -> ( docs file and openapi.json file can be recognized with some prefix but it adds additional prefix of the same prefix.) So planned to go with custom api for open api generation. To generate the swagger we created a custom api, Calling it would call the openapi.json file and shows the swagger. The main issue here is the parameters in the API are resorted by itself and it is sorting in different unknown order.

Python library -apispec- https://pypi.org/project/apispec/

The above python library is used to generate docs.

For Eg.

- A user tries to access this api through open api docs and parameters are sorted in this order

```
{
"id": "integer",
"name": "string" 
"description": "string" 
}

 * User 2 is trying to access this api through the same url, api's parameters are shows like below

{
"name": "string" 
"description": "string" 
"id": "integer",
}
```

Is there any way to handle this sorting during a custom api call for generating the open api docs ?